# Deploying a seam project in JBOSS (Developer Studio)

Tags: jakarta-ee, configuration, jboss, seam

I trying to get some experience with the [Seam Framework - JBoss Seam](http://www.seamframework.org/).
Me and a friend would like to develop a simple application, but we can't get anywhere. When he creates a project, he can run it and it all goes well. But when i'm trying to run the same project, it won't show up in the browser saying

> ### HTTP Status 404 -
>
> type Status report
>   message
>
> ### description The requested resource () is not available.
>
> JBossWeb/2.0.0.GA_CP

We are running on the following configuration.

- JRE 1.5
- JBOSS Developer studio 2.0
- JBOSS EAP 4.3
- SEAM 2.1

Based on the 404 not found status, I figured the project was not getting deployed to the server. When looking at the server log I see the following error:

> 10:16:14,740 ERROR [ContainerBase] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Looking up that error gets me nowhere, every thread about it hasn't been resolved, so I hoped someone could help me out here.

By the way, i don't have a working database yet, is it possible this can be blocking the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google for "Bad version number in .class file", you should find the explanation for the error: Your code was compiled with a newer version than you are running it with. Since the class cannot be loaded, your application won't be deployed.

Besides, if you have the chance to start on the "green field", you should definitely look for newer technologies. The versions of your JRE and JBoss are so hopelessly outdated, that you are looking for trouble and won't get much help when having problems. And Seam 2.1 (even though we had it until recently in projects) is no longer necessary if you are using JavaEE 6.

So here's my recommendation: Get familiar with a recent IDE like eclipse Juno or Netbeans 7 and also with Maven (since if you like Maven or not, most of the examples you'll find, will be using Maven) and check out the [JBoss Tutorials](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/get-started/) (which are quite good).